# Loop a query until result is found

Tags: mysql, sql, string, loops, match

i'm having trouble creating a simple 'while loop'.

How can i loop a select query and remove the last character of a string until results are found?

eg.:

```
myfield
_______
1stone
1stick
1stove
1stones
2stick
2stove
2stone
2sticks
3stoves
3stone
3stick
3stove


[loop1] SELECT myfield FROM table WHERE myfield LIKE  '1story%'  -> 0 results
[loop2] SELECT myfield FROM table WHERE myfield LIKE  '1stor%'   -> 0 results
[loop3] SELECT myfield FROM table WHERE myfield LIKE  '1sto%'    -> 3 results
```

would need to result in

```
1stone
1stones
1stove
```

or

```
[loop1] SELECT myfield FROM table WHERE myfield LIKE '2somevalue%'  -> 0 results 
[loop2] SELECT myfield FROM table WHERE myfield LIKE '2somevalu%'   -> 0 results 
[loop3] SELECT myfield FROM table WHERE myfield LIKE '2someval%'   -> 0 results 
[loop4] SELECT myfield FROM table WHERE myfield LIKE '2someva%'   -> 0 results 
[loop5] SELECT myfield FROM table WHERE myfield LIKE '2somev%'   -> 0 results 
[loop6] SELECT myfield FROM table WHERE myfield LIKE '2some%'   -> 0 results 
[loop7] SELECT myfield FROM table WHERE myfield LIKE '2som%'   -> 0 results 
[loop8] SELECT myfield FROM table WHERE myfield LIKE '2so%'  -> 0 results 
[loop9] SELECT myfield FROM table WHERE myfield LIKE '2s%'   -> 4 results
```

would need to result in

```
2stick
2sticks
2stone
2stove
```

i've been trying this but with no luck so far

```
SET @counter = 0,  @results = 0, @value = 'somevalue'

WHILE ( @counter <= LENGTH(@value) AND @results = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @qry = "SELECT COUNT(myfield) FROM table WHERE myfield LIKE '" + LEFT(@value, LENGTH(@value)-@Counter) + "%'  " 
    SET @results = (SELECT COUNT(myfield) FROM table WHERE myfield LIKE LEFT(@value, LENGTH(@value)-@Counter) + '%') 
    SET @counter  = @Counter  + 1 
END 


exec @qry
```

Comment: in sql, which rdms are you using and what have you tried so far?

Comment: i'm using mysql,  i want to do it in just SQL an not workaround using other scripting liek php or vb

Comment: you need a procedure for that Length gets the number of character and LEFT get you the left part, the rest is a while loop, so give a try

Comment: i've been trying all sort of things so i thought i'm must have been totally in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a procrdure for this as i said

This uses dynamic sql because the code else would be vulnerable to sql injection

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab
>     (`myfield` varchar(7))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO tab
>     (`myfield`)
> VALUES
>     ('1stone'),
>     ('1stick'),
>     ('1stove'),
>     ('1stones'),
>     ('2stick'),
>     ('2stove'),
>     ('2stone'),
>     ('2sticks'),
>     ('3stoves'),
>     ('3stone'),
>     ('3stick'),
>     ('3stove')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name(_searchtext varchar(100))
> BEGIN
>    DECLARE _mylen int DEFAULT 0;
>    SET _mylen := LENGTH(_searchtext);
>    myloop: WHILE _myLen > 0 DO
>        
>        SET @sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @i FROM tab WHERE myfield LIKE  ?';
>         set @text := (SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(_searchtext,_mylen), '%'));
>         PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
>         EXECUTE stmt USING @text;
>         DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
>        IF @i > 0 then
>            SET @sql = 'SELECT myfield FROM tab WHERE myfield LIKE  ?';
>         PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
>         EXECUTE stmt USING @text;
>         DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;           
>            LEAVE myloop;
>        end if;
>        SET _myLen := _myLen -1;
>    END WHILE;
>    IF  @i = 0 then
>        SELECT 'No entries' AS result;
>    END IF;
> END;
> ```

> ```
> CALL procedure_name('1story')
> ```
>
> ```
> | myfield |
> | :------ |
> | 1stone  |
> | 1stove  |
> | 1stones |
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CALL procedure_name('abc')
> ```
>
> ```
> | result     |
> | :--------- |
> | No entries |
>
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b8dda59adff7a2a660a0c60433898afa)*

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly.

But why was my code not working?

Comment: mysql has no exec